# manipulating Q objects, Adding new condition dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-q

I have a Q object like this.

```
params = Q(salt_spray__iregex=keyword) | Q(special_function__iregex=keyword) | Q(comment__iregex=keyword)
```

Here When I filter my model on the basis of this, things work fine.

`Model.objects.filter(params)`

But I want to do the following.

```
params = Q(salt_spray__iregex=keyword) | Q(special_function__iregex=keyword) | Q(comment__iregex=keyword)
if data.get('market'):
    params[project__market] = data['market'] # not sure about this step. 
Model.objects.filter(params)
```

### Code after Solution

data = self.cleaned_data

```
keyword = data['keyword']
params = Q()
if keyword:
    params |= Q(salt_spray__iregex=keyword) | Q(special_function__iregex=keyword) | Q(comment__iregex=keyword) # Note OR Operator. 

if data['market']:
    params &= Q(project__market=data['market']) # Note here AND Operator 
innovations = Innovation.objects.filter(params)
return innovations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *or* the Q objects with the `|` operator:

```
params = Q(salt_spray__iregex=keyword) | Q(special_function__iregex=keyword) | Q(comment__iregex=keyword)
if data.get('market'):
    params |= Q(project__market=data['market'])
Model.objects.filter(params)
```

Or use `operator.or_` as @rinti has mentioned.

Comment: Excellent solution. You can combine AND or OR operators accordingly.

Comment: @Jack, be aware when combining both _AND_ and _OR_ operators. If you want to _AND_ 2 groups of queries, you need to do `&= <the other group` instead of a single `&=` for the _AND_ and then `|=` for the other group's elements.

Comment: Do you mean `&=<` ?? What is the use of `<`?

Comment: @Jack, sorry, I've missed the closing `>` - it should be `&= <the other group>`.

Comment: Perfect, Can you see my Updated code above and see its correct?

Comment: @Jack, I think it should be fine. It's equivalent to `(salt_spray | special_function) & project__market`. It could get messy if you did _OR_ something later on, e.g. _OR_ ing `Q1` and `Q2` would give `(((salt_spray | special_function) & project__market) | Q1) | Q2)`

Comment: Great, If i need to do more ORs and ANDs I will try to simplify it.

Comment: @Jack, just remember that `Q1 &= Q2` is equivalent to `Q1 = Q1 & Q2` which is equivalent to `(conditions for Q1) & (conditions for Q2)`. Same for `|`. If you need to add a group of conditions with the same operator using a different operator, remember to first create a `Q` object that encapsulates the group with given operator, then `&=` or `|=` it with the rest of the filters.

Answer (score 0):

import `operator` then you can do it like this:

```
params = []

# Add as much as you like to your list dynamically
params.append(Q(something))

Model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, params))
```